# Deploying to Azure with Terraform: Error building ARM Config

Tags: azure, terraform, github-actions

When I try to deploy to terraform using azure, I get the following error:

> Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only
> supported as a User (not a Service Principal).

I am using the following task:

```
- name: Azure Login
  uses: azure/login@v1
  with:
    creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS  }}
```

The `AZURE_CREDENTIALS` Secret looks like this, which IS a service principal.

```
{
"clientId": "XXX",
"clientSecret": "XXX",
"subscriptionId": "XXX",
"tenantId": "XXX",
}
```

Note: I don't have the clientSecret from above separately, so I need to use AZURE_CREDENTIALS directly. Is there a flag or anything else I am missing?

Comment: How did you create service principal?

Answer (score 0):

Add each parameter as single secret rather than a single one with JSON content, then change the Azure Login step to the following:

```
  - name: Azure Login
    uses: Azure/login@v1
    with:
      creds: '{"clientId":"${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}","clientSecret":"${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}","subscriptionId":"${{ secrets.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}","tenantId":"${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}"}'
```